# PHP (pdo) limit changes in database and change from html

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I’m new at php and I got some problem that I don’t know how to fix, I made 
A HTML form that should change the name of a database

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form action="name.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

HTML form is also connected to PHP edit script

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "tbl_product";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql ="UPDATE tbl_product SET name='$name' WHERE id = ID LIMIT 1";

    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
    echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
    header("Refresh:0; url=products.php");
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

The script that I run won’t change the database name and if it changes it changes all database names.
For now, looks like the script runs fine but nothing happened.
I need to limit the changing data from database so one change does not change all.

Comment: Can you show some example records? What is your "id" field like? `WHERE id = ID` looks wrong to me.

Comment: Is your _database_ name really tbl_product!?

Comment: Well thats the database, i created one script delete and i limit it like WHERE id = ID LIMIT 1, and it worked.

Comment: @DedaMraz what is ID?

Comment: i got tbl_product: id, name, image, price. ID is 1

Comment: Where did u define ID=1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query seems to be faulty. According to a quick test I ran on a local MySQL instance the condition `WHERE id = ID` seems to be always true (it is probably evaluated kind of like `1=1` would be. Therefore your query is the same as `UPDATE tbl_product SET name='$name' LIMIT 1` and because of that it is updating all records without the LIMIT.

Also you are not properly utilizing prepared statements (which is not part of the problem, but you should do it the right way anyway).

```
$id = 1; // assign the id of the record you want to change
$name = "the new name";
$sql ="UPDATE tbl_product SET name = :name WHERE id = :id";

// Prepare statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

// execute the query and bind values to placeholders in the query
$stmt->execute([
    ':name' => $name,
    ':id' => $id
]);
```

That way no SQL injection is possible and you properly use the id in your query and can remove the LIMIT part.

**Edit 1 (Redirecting):**

Redirecting and sending headers is a whole different topic. Basically you would do it like this (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) for more details):

```
header('Location: products.php');
exit;
```

Also you can not use `echo` before `header`. It will throw an error. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) for more info.

**Edit 2 (Changing random records):**

Changing random records seems to be a strange application, but it would probably work by using this query instead:

```
UPDATE tbl_product SET name = :name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

You also need to remove the `:id` part from the `$stmt->execute` call, since you don't have an :id parameter in your query anymore.

Comment: I need to choose what I wane change so I can’t only change one whit id 1 there will be much more. For now it only change one and i got this massage from MAMP UPDATE tbl_product SET name = :name WHERE id = :id
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Comment: Did you add the parameters in the `$stmt->execute` part (last lines of my example)? Then the error should not happen. Obviously you can assign different values to $id and change other records as well. This example just shows how to do it for the record with id = 1.

Comment: I change it from HTML form and when i put your code in it change it in "the new name"  but it doesn’t return me to products.php

Comment: Yes i add the parameters

Comment: Me bad you are right it works now, I forgot to put the coma. 

Comment: To assign the id of the record i want to change, i need to pick up random records from me data and change it, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: I added a part for how to redirect to "products.php" in my answer.

Comment: Thanks it works, but can you tell me more about me previous question. To assign the id of the record i want to change, i need to pick up random records from me data and change it, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Changing random records seems like an odd application, but I added it to my answer. If you have more questions consider creating a new question, so this one does not get too bloated. And if you think my answer solved your problem please accept it! :-)

Comment: Edit 2 (Changing random records): wont work i run it 4 times

Comment: Yes, but what does "does not work" mean? Do you get an error? Also the value of $name has to be different of course, otherwise the change would just do nothing.

Comment: Il do a new question this is to much bloated. Danke

Answer (score 0):

You have to set id in where clause, then it will update only one row matched with the id, You do not need to set LIMIT 1.

```
$sql ="UPDATE tbl_product SET name='$name' WHERE id = $id";
```

You can get id from hidden input in the form.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form action="name.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Error at this line  $sql ="UPDATE tbl_product SET name='$name' WHERE id = $id";

Comment: Do you send the id from HTML form and receive it in variable $id ?

Comment: Yes i sent it from HTML